# Console-based game in Java to demonstrate Solid principles and abstractions

Tags: java, object-oriented, role-playing-game

I've written a console-based demo while learning about the Solid principles. Along the way, I've become exceedingly paranoid about whether I'm writing good code or not.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class Entity {  //Base template for all game entities...

private String name;

public Entity(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    displayEntityName();
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String newName)
{
    name = newName;
}

private void displayEntityName()
{
    System.out.println(name + " entity created...");
}



public class Player extends Entity {

private String[] inventory; //Player will have an inventory.
private int itemsInInventory;
private static final Random RAND = new Random();

public Player(String name) {
    super(name);
    inventory = new String[25]; //Default inventory size.
}

public void attack(Enemy enemy) //Player can attack all enemy types.
{
    System.out.println(super.getName() + " attacked the enemy...");
}

public void findLegendaryWeapon()
{
    inventory[0] = WeaponConstants.LEGENDARY_WEAPONS
    [RAND.nextInt(WeaponConstants.LEGENDARY_WEAPONS.length)];
    itemsInInventory++;
}

public void equiptWeapon()
{
    System.out.println(super.getName() + " equipted a weapon...");
}

public void searchChest()
{
    System.out.println(super.getName() + " searched the chest and found nothing...");
}


}

public enum WeaponConstants{ //Legendary weapon constants.

BOW_OF_THE_MAJOR_ARCHER(), BLOOD_LETTER,
DAWNFANG, FROZEN_TOUCH;

public static final String[] LEGENDARY_WEAPONS = {DAWNFANG.name(), 
        BLOOD_LETTER.name(), FROZEN_TOUCH.name(), BOW_OF_THE_MAJOR_ARCHER.name()};

}


public interface Enemy { //Enemy interface...
    void attack(Player player);
}


public class Ghoul extends Entity implements Enemy { //An example of a standard enemy class.

    public Ghoul(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void attack(Player player) {
        System.out.println(super.getName() + " attacked " + player.getName());
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, I mainly want to know if I'm violating any of the Solid principles. My main concern is with my player class. I have quite a few methods in the class that do different types of things but they are all related to the player. Is this in any way violating the SRP principle?

Also, I wanted to know if my abstractions are correct and well-designed. Does this represent good coding style when used to develop more serious apps? I only have one year of experience, so I'm trying to solidify good practices early on. All input would be appreciated.

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/175933)

Answer (score 2):

thanks for sharing your code

I know that this isn't a huge amount of code, but I'm going to look at it assuming that we will want to be able to add additional features and expand upon the code that's already here.

**Redundant Comments**

comments should say ***why*** you're doing something, not ***what*** you're doing.
This line

```
private String[] inventory; //Player will have an inventory.
```

is an example of a particularly bad offender. If I have a `Player` class, and it has an `inventory` member variable. We know that a `Player` will have an `inventory`, you don't need to write a comment saying what the code is already telling us.

Let's take a look at your `Entity` class. If we look in the constructor, we can see that the constructor is causing some **side effects**. In this case, it's printing to the console. In general, when I construct an object, I assume there will be no side effects or other unexpected behaviour. It's perfectly reasonable to provide a method to do this (in your case `displayEntityName`) but I would not include this in the constructor.

**Consider making your classes immutable where possible**

Unless you need to provide getter and setter methods for an instance variable, you should just leave them out entirely and make the variable final. I think here `name` is a good candidate, a getter seems reasonable, but I don't think you'd ever really need a setter. In a standard RPG or game, the player or enemy names don't change. They can be marked final.

```
private final String name;
```

see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen

have a look at the arguments for and against using getters and setters. I won't also recommend reading up on the benefits (and drawbacks) of writing immutable classes.

**Avoid using Strings to represent more complex Objects**

You're currently representing your inventory as an array of Strings. I would argue that an `Item` is far more than just a String. I would rather see an `Item` class. This could be a super class or interface that all items in your game could derive from / implement.

Some class that come to mind could be, `Weapon`, `Armour`, `Accessory` etc. If all of these things are represented as a single String, you're restricting what you can do. Additionally, I would not use an array for this situation. How about an `Inventory` class.

```
public class Inventory {
    private final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(Item item){ // can be weapon, armour etc.
        items.add(item);
    }

    public int numItems(){
        return items.size();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, this `Inventory` class has the **single responsibility** of representing and maintaining this list of items.

and your `Player` class can just have an Inventory

```
private final Inventory inventory;
```

Or even just put it in the `Entity` class. This way an `Enemy` can have an inventory too.

Notice how I used a `List` instead of an array. This can be resized and already has a `list.size()` method to tell you how many elements are in it. No need to keep track of that stuff yourself!

This `Inventory` can now become a lot more useful than just an array of Strings.

Your current `Player` class has **two** responsibilities that jump out. One is providing `Player` behaviour, but it's also maintaining the inventory by keeping track of it's size. Now the `Inventory` class is in charge of this.

This method signature

```
public void searchChest()
```

At the moment this method simply prints that the `Player` is searching a chest, why not provide the option to search any `Chest` object.

```
public void searchChest(Chest chest)
```

and a `Chest` could look like

```
public class Chest {
    private final List<Item> contents;

    ...

    public List<Item> open(){
        return new ArrayList<>(contents);
    }
}
```

Then in the `searchChest` method, the Items from the `Chest` can be added to the `Inventory`.

Similarly to the Chest method, this method

```
public void equiptWeapon()
```

firstly, there's a typo here. It should be

```
public void equipWeapon()
```

Secondly, why not be able to provide a weapon

```
public void equipWeapon(Weapon weapon)
```

At the moment in your Enemy interface you have this method.

```
void attack(Player player);
```

What if you want to have Enemies fight each other, different factions etc.
There's no need to limit the potential targets, how about

```
void attack(Entity entity);
```

Some final points to consider.

When you `attack` another entity, you could get the currently equipped `Weapon` and the other entity's currently equipped `Armour` and do some simple math based on their `Stats`

instead of a `displayEntityName` method, you could just override `toString` and then print the `Entity` directly in the calling code.

Before you start coding anything, think about what Objects could be involved in your System/Game in real world terms, then start thinking about how these could be implemented as Objects in your code.

Instead of `WeaponConstants`, why not just make a `Collection` of Weapon objects.

Hopefully this review was useful for you.

Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. This wasn't meant to be a completed demo and I just wrote it up quickly to get some quick feedback but I do see the attack method problem and the inventory tip was very nice. 

The reason I made only enemies implement enemy is because if I made the entity abstract class have an abstract attack method, then the player could potentially attack itself, as it is an entity. I guess the concept of overriding methods just escaped me though. Lol.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> private void displayEntityName()
> ```

As this method is in the `Entity` class, "Entity" as part of the method name is superfluous.

---

> ```
> Player.public void attack(Enemy enemy)
> Enemy.void attack(Player player);
> ```

I predict duplicate code and frustrating type clashes as 'Player', 'Enemy', 'Goal' objects interact, desperate attempts at type-casting resulting in unnecessary classes and interfaces, etc.

Could you say 'Player', 'Enemy', 'Goal' are all `combatants`?

---

> ```
> @Override
> public void attack(Player player)
> ```

Overriding an `interface` method doesn't seem to make sense. Perhaps I'm missing something?

---

Inconsistancies:

`Player` subclass directly implements `attack()` method but `Ghoul` gets `attack()` via an `interface`. Yet all of these inherit `Entity`. Why can't `Entity` have an abstract or virtual method maybe with some default behavior? Or why can't all of these guys implement the `Enemy` interface?

The idea of an `enemy` is one sided. I say this because only one class implements that interface. Yet a `player` is a `ghoul`'s enemy and a `ghoul` is a `player`'s enemy; but the current design does not capture this commutative property. I'm not saying the answer is everyone implements the `Enemy` interface.

This lopsided enemy concept also manifests by the fact there are `attack` methods that take different types.

`player`s have weapon methods, but `ghoul`s do not. Another thing that should be consistent and expressed in some kind of common design construct.

Cohesion:

In terms of fighting each other these objects are all the same thing conceptually, let's say "combatants". This idea should consolidate the differently-typed `attack` methods and interfaces (and more to come I imagine). With a more abstract type, any combatant can fight any other combatant. Then it's other properties, methods, inheritance, etc. that differentiates a `player`, `enemy`, `ghoul`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for that. I made the enemy interface thinking that I would never have a situation where an enemy would have to attack another enemy but I see where that makes it way less flexible in case that need arises later on. Also, i didn't let entity have the attack method because not all entities will have an attack behavior. If I let the abstract entity class have an attack method, then potentially, the player could attack itself. I guess the concept of overriding escaped me though. LOL.